# How to port MD5 signature code from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, .net

I'm trying to port the following Java code to C#, but so far it still says that the signature is invalid.

```cs
private static String generateSignStr(Map<String, String> params, String key) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    params.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(entry -> {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append('&');
        }
        sb.append(entry.getKey()).append('=');
        sb.append(entry.getValue());
    });
    sb.append('&').append("api_secret")
            .append('=').append(key);
    return sb.toString();
}

private static String sign(String target) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error("Fail to get MD5 instance");
        return null;
    }
    md.update(target.getBytes());
    byte[] dg = md.digest();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(dg.length * 2);
    for (byte dgByte : dg) {
        int current = dgByte & 0xff;
        if (current < 16) {
            output.append("0");
        }
        output.append(Integer.toString(current, 16));
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

```cs
private static string GenerateSign(Dictionary<string, object> query, string apiSecret)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var queryParameterString = string.Join("&",
        query.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kvp.Value.ToString()))
            .Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value.ToString())}"));
    sb.Append(queryParameterString);

    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        sb.Append('&');
    }

    sb.Append("api_secret=").Append(apiSecret);

    return sb.ToString();
}

private static string Sign(string source)
{
    using var md5 = MD5.Create();
    var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

## Edit:

This fixed it. However, it would be nice if someone knows a way to lexicographically sort the dictionary inside that method just like the Java code.

```cs
var @params = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "api_key", _apiKey },
            { "req_time", now },
            { "op", "sub.personal" }
        };

        var javaSorted = @params.OrderBy(item => item.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);

var signature = Sign(GenerateSign(javaSorted, _apiSecret));
```

Comment: `target.getBytes()` will return various encodings depending on your OS, JVM, and Java version. Unless you don't care if the bytes are Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 or EBCDIC, you should never use it for anything and instead prefer `target.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: Also, on recent versions of Java, you can use `HexFormat.of().format(db)` instead of the loop to format the digest.

Comment: @DavidConrad, thanks but I'm not using the Java code. I'm trying to convert it to C#.

Comment: What does that mean, then, "it still says that the signature is invalid"? I thought you were comparing the signatures produced by the Java code vs. the C# code. The C# code is explicitly using UTF-8, so maybe that is the problem. "It," whatever it is, does not expect the signature to be done with UTF-8, but rather some other unspecified encoding.

Comment: @DavidConrad, I'm not sure because the exchange doesn't really provide that information. https://github.com/mxcdevelop/mexc-api-demo/blob/7991f8a3a17e6ba5dc2cf55133532ab145b0c878/Java/src/main/java/com/mexc/example/spot/websocket/MexcSpotRawWsExample.java#L88 The Java code works fine

Comment: The main difference I can see is that they are using different character sets. You can check if the string is the same by adding some debugging code to each of them, but most likely it's the encoding. You can check what encoding Java is using by looking at `java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()` or `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`. And then change C# to use the same.

Comment: @DavidConrad, the support told me that the lexicographical sort is causing it.

Comment: @DavidConrad, confirmed it was causing it. Now I gotta find a way to wrap the sorting inside the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GenerateSign` method you can just create instance of `SortedDictionary` based on dictionary passed as parameter:

```
private static string GenerateSign(Dictionary<string, object> query, string apiSecret)
{
    var sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<string, object>(query, StringComparer.Ordinal);
    // rest of the method
}
```

Or you can do even better (note the important change from `Dictionary` to `IDictionary`):

```
private static string GenerateSign(IDictionary<string, object> query, string apiSecret)
{
    query = new SortedDictionary<string, object>(query, StringComparer.Ordinal);
    // rest of the method
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted